# Steps to solve $\lim_{x \to 0,x<0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$ for $f(x) = |x|$

Tags: calculus, limits

In my math book in the introduction to differential calculus there is a function defined as: $f(x) = |x|$ and $x_0=0$.

Then the following equation is given for the left side of the graph (below zero):

$$\lim_{x \to 0,x<0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x \to 0,x<0} \frac{-x}{x} = -1$$

Is this correct? Should't the minus in the second term be on the denominator instead of on the numerator?

Comment: In numerator it comes from $|x|=-x$ for $x<0$, while denominator remains intact.

Comment: If $x$ is negative, then $-x$ is positive  That's right: $-x$ is positive.  I think if you understand this, then you will know the answer to your question.

Comment: Ah, I finally got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. The minus sign comes from the fact that $|x| = -x$ when $x\leq 0$.

For example, $|-3| = -(-3) = 3$.